# set textsize for multiple textview with different ids

Tags: android, menu, textview

I am trying to set textsize for multiple textview with different ids. Also, every textview in its own fragment that view and slide in view pager.

**BUT, the problem is this code is working just for first and second id and the rest did not change. Also, if i remove if (sT != null) I got null point error.**

```
   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;


        case R.id.small_fond_size:
            int[] ids = {R.id.text_view_thread0, R.id.text_view_thread1, R.id.text_view_thread2, R.id.text_view_thread3,
                    R.id.text_view_thread4, R.id.text_view_thread5, R.id.text_view_thread6, R.id.text_view_thread7,
                    R.id.text_view_thread8, R.id.text_view_thread9, R.id.text_view_thread10, R.id.text_view_thread11,
                    R.id.text_view_thread12, R.id.text_view_thread13, R.id.text_view_thread14, R.id.text_view_thread15,
                    R.id.text_view_thread16, R.id.text_view_thread17, R.id.text_view_thread18};
            for (int id : ids){
                TextView sT = (TextView) findViewById(id);
                if (sT != null)
                sT.setTextSize(9);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is anything wrong with this snippet

```
int[] ids = {R.id.text_view_thread0, R.id.text_view_thread1, R.id.text_view_thread2, R.id.text_view_thread3,
                R.id.text_view_thread4, R.id.text_view_thread5, R.id.text_view_thread6, R.id.text_view_thread7,
                R.id.text_view_thread8, R.id.text_view_thread9, R.id.text_view_thread10, R.id.text_view_thread11,
                R.id.text_view_thread12, R.id.text_view_thread13, R.id.text_view_thread14, R.id.text_view_thread15,
                R.id.text_view_thread16, R.id.text_view_thread17, R.id.text_view_thread18};
        for (int id : ids){
            TextView sT = (TextView) findViewById(id);
            if (sT != null)
            sT.setTextSize(9);
```

I tried this and it is setting incremental font size as below :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int[] ids = {R.id.t1, R.id.t2,  R.id.t3,  R.id.t4,  R.id.t5,  R.id.t6,  R.id.t7,  R.id.t8};
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        TextView sT = (TextView) findViewById(ids[i]);
        if (sT != null)
            sT.setTextSize(9 + i);
    }
}
```

This is working fine. Because I don't have permission to comment below question, I had to write it in answer. Please, give more hints about your problem.

Github reference : https://github.com/kuldeepiitg/FontSize

Comment: I don't think it is because of the typo, but check "case R.id.small_fond_size:" for id mismatch. fond instead of font.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! .. this is totally working if all the textview in the same activity. but i am using viewpager with 18 fragments each fragment has a textview.. i am trying to change all of them from the main activity.

Comment: Are you doing something like this for fragment?

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();

Comment: i am returning (return new Thread0_Fragment();) from the  viewpager adapter

Comment: Is it a multiple tab page?

Comment: I think while changing fragments you are using new instance of fragment by calling constructor, its view is populated using layout file. So your changes are getting reset to original as you are making changes at run time.

Comment: Yes It is 18 tabs .. what do you think? what is the solution of this problem. I am trying to give the user the ability for changing the font size to read easily.  I tried to shrink my project to just one fragment with one activity and i failed.

Comment: So what is your architecture? Let's talk in chat room.